# Derivative of squared Frobenius norm of a matrix with transpose

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces

How can I derivative this squared Frobenius norm
$||\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I||^2_F$, where $\mathbf A$ is a $D \times K$ matrix.
I tried to do it by myself and my result is $4(\mathbf A^T \mathbf A - \mathbf I)\mathbf A$. This result is obviously with dimension unmatching error.

Here are my steps:
$$\frac{\partial ||\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I||^2_F}{\partial \mathbf A} = \frac{trace\{(\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I)^T(\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I)\}}{\partial \mathbf A}=\frac{\partial trace\{(\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I)^2\}}{\partial \mathbf A}=\frac{\partial trace\{(\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I)^2\}}{\partial (\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I)}\frac{\partial (\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I)}{\partial \mathbf A}=2(\mathbf A^{T}\mathbf A - \mathbf I)2\mathbf A = 4(\mathbf A^T \mathbf A - \mathbf I)\mathbf A$$

Answer (score 1):

Define the symmetric matrix
$$X = A^TA - I$$
Write the norm in terms of this new variable. Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|X\|_F^2 \;=\; X:X \\
d\phi &= (X:dX + dX:X) \\
 &= 2X:dX \\
 &= 2X:d(A^TA) \\
 &= 2X:dA^T + 2X:dA \\
 &= 2X^T:dA + 2X:dA \\
 &= 2(X^T+X):dA \\
 &= 4X:dA \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A} &= 4X \;=\; 4(A^TA-I) \\
}$$
In the above, a colon is used as a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
The properties of the trace allow the terms in the product to be rearranged in several ways.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
A:BC &= B^TA:C \;=\; AC^T:B \;=\; \ldots \\
}$$